# Clarification of the Veto Card in El Grande

Tags: el-grande

In El Grande, it is possible to collect a Veto card, which can be used to prevent a player from performing the action of the card they choose. It can be used to veto one card in the current round or the next round.

It says something like

> when a player starts to perform their action, the veto card is played, and prevents the action.

But, does the player have to explain their full action, or just their intention to use the card? For example.

If Player A has the Veto Card, and Player B decides to play the Move King card, does Player B have to make known

- Their intention to move the king
- Where they intend to move the king (which indeed may be to leave it where it currently is).

Or can they get away with just declaring their intention to move the king, and leave some element of doubt for Player B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some clarifications of the Veto rules personally corrected and confirmed by the game designer Wolfgang Kramer:

> *9. Veto: If you have taken this card, then lay it in front of you
>   where the other players can see it. You may use it to veto any one
>   special action that a player wishes to carry out either during the
>   remainder of the current round or during the next round. You may only
>   veto a special action, the normal placement of Caballeros is carried
>   out as usual. You may only use your Veto once, and during the special
>   action is carrying out. You may not cancel an action once carried out.
>   Once you have used your Veto you must return the card to the box, if
>   you have not used your Veto by the end of the round after the one in
>   which you took the card, then you must give it up.
>
> The opponents can ask for or come to an agreement with you about what
>   they can do. * An opponent wants move some Caballeros, he can ask :
>   "If I move this Caballeros from ... to ..., you play the Veto card?"
>   or "May I move this Caballero, and this else?" or other similar
>   questions.
>
> If an opponent doesn't want to carry out the special action, you can't
>   force him thanks to the Veto, because it can prevent (but can't force)
>   an action.
>
> 9.1. Veto & Special action addressed to only one player:
>
> The player who is on turn determines the order of the steps of a
>   special action (rule 4), so the Veto can stop his special action at
>   any time before it ends.
>
> - "INTRIGANT:4 BELIEBIGE CABALLEROS AUF DEM SPIELPLAN BELIEBIG
>     UMSETZEN: The player may remove up to 4 Caballeros (their own and/or
>     opponent's) from the board, and replace them in another region or in
>     the Castillo.": A player may move four Caballeros. He has already
>     moved two. You were pleased with these moves. Now he plans to move one
>     more. You don't like that, so you play your Veto and he can't execute
>     the remainder of the special action.

There's more where this came from, but I thought I'd stop there!  I think this illustrates the power of Veto quite nicely: you can indeed find out what a player plans to do with their move before choosing to veto it; and you can even use the Veto partway through a move if it begins to take a direction you don't like!